# how to get only pixels from inside a irregular shape from uiimageview in iphone?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, core-graphics, bitmapdata

i want to get only those pixels which are inside an irregular shape..using core graphics not openGL.here is an image where i have drawn an irregular shape.

[image]

and here is the drawing code

```
- (void)touchesMoved:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {
    if(drawLineClicked)
    {
        UITouch *touch = [touches anyObject];
        if ([touch view] == EditImageView)
        {
        lastPoint = [touch locationInView:self.view];
        [self drawLines:10.0 andColorWithRed:1.0 Green:0.0 Blue:0.0 Alpha:1.0];
        [self.view setNeedsDisplay];
        currentPoint = lastPoint;
        }
    }
}


-(void)drawLines:(CGFloat)withWidth andColorWithRed:(CGFloat)red Green:(CGFloat)green Blue:(CGFloat)blue Alpha:(CGFloat)alpha
{
UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(Image.size);
    [EditImageView.image drawInRect:CGRectMake(0, 0, Image.size.width, Image.size.height)];
 ctx = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();
CGContextSetLineCap(ctx, kCGLineCapRound);
CGContextSetAllowsAntialiasing(ctx,TRUE);
CGContextFlush(ctx);
//sets the line width for a graphic context
CGContextSetLineWidth(ctx,withWidth);
//set the line colour
CGContextSetRGBStrokeColor(ctx, red, green, blue, alpha);  
CGContextMoveToPoint(ctx, currentPoint.x, currentPoint.y);     
CGContextAddLineToPoint(ctx, lastPoint.x,lastPoint.y);      
CGContextStrokePath(ctx);
EditImageView.image = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Here's just tossing out an idea:

Instead of drawing the red line directly on the image, I'd duplicate the image, add it as a new layer on top of the original image, and give it a totally transparent mask (so the new layer is "invisible").

Then when the user draws the red line, use that to build a path as a mask on the invisible layer.  When the path is finished, fill in the path with black (on the mask), to make that portion totally opaque.  You could maybe then resize the top layer (that's been masked) to be the bounding rectangle of the drawn path.

The opaque pixels on the topmost layer will then be the ones that were bounded by the drawn path, and you can then do what you please with it (draw it to a new UIImage, etc).

Hope that makes sense...

Comment: could you please post a sample source for this

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at my old sample code project here: [Cropped Image](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/samplecode/Cropped_Image/index.html)

It's for Cocoa, not Cocoa Touch, but the idea is the same.  You can crop an image by compositing using the SourceIn compositing mode.

Comment: your sample code is excellent.can you tell me how do i show color pallete on iphone then choose a color

Comment: I'm a bit surprised that there doesn't seem to be a color picker in the UIKit.  I guess you'll have to write one.